# How to get post id to use in the front page?

Tags: wordpress

I am very newbie in creating Wordpress Theme and I have one question that I cannot find it via google. I would like to change the inline style into wp_add_inline_style function. After changes, my style now shows very pretty in post page, but do not change anything in the frontpage because of the post id. I tried to use get_the_ID(), get_queried_object_id() and nothing happens. How can I solve this problem?

```
function metabox_inline_style() {
     $id = get_the_ID();

    if( 'quote' == get_post_format() || is_front_page() ) {

    $quote_active = get_post_meta($id, 'q_active', true);
    $quote_color = get_post_meta($id, 'q_color', true);
    $quote_bgcolor = get_post_meta($id, 'q_bgcolor', true);
    $font_size = get_post_meta($id, 'q_font', true);
         $custom_metabox_css = "
        .quote-style {
            color: {$quote_color};
            background-color: {$quote_bgcolor};
            font-size: {$font_size};
        }
        .quote-style p {
            color: {$quote_color};
        }"; 

        wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_metabox_css );
        }
    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'metabox_inline_style' );
```

More information. 
This function is in the functions.php file.
I used page-home.php and SiteOrigin page builder to create the front page.
I tried Global $post and $id = $post->ID, and it is still not work. And, I check print_r($id). It does not show the same ID in the front page(ID = 43) and post page (ID = 104).

Comment: Is your front page a WP page or post list?

Comment: Does anything change if your reverse the if condition: `if( is_front_page() || 'quote' == get_post_format() )` ?

Comment: @martynasma I use page-home.php and have SiteOrigin page builder to create the front page. .

Comment: @dingo_d Nothing changes.

Comment: You could try with `$id = $post->ID;`?

Comment: I tried it. Global $post, and $id = $post->ID Nothing happens.

Comment: Last straw, try with `$page` instead of post. When you do `print_r($id);` does it gives you a page id at all?

Comment: I would like to inform one thing. After I check print_r($id), the frontpage not use the post page id. It uses the frontpage id.

Comment: What do you mean frontpage id? Can you elaborate? Update your post.

Comment: Do you mean $page->ID ?

Comment: Sorry. It is page id.

Comment: Do you have a page that you know is used as a front page? (Settings > Reading) If not, then your WP is assuming you just are displaying latest blog posts (even if your theme/plugin is preventing them from actually appearing and replacing it with some other content)

Comment: @martynasma Yes, I do.

Comment: Then `get_the_ID()` **should** most definitely return the id of the current page. If it does not, the only thing that comes to mind, is that some plugin or custom functionality in the theme is interfering with it. Try disabling plugins one by one and changing theme to pinpoint which one does that, then work on resolving it.

Comment: I disabled plugins except the Siteorigin page builder plugin. It is still not resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I correct my code and finally I can do it as following. Thank you everybody for your kindly advise.

```
function option_save_post($post_id) {

    $myOptions = get_option('MyOptions');

    $myOptions[$post_id]['q_color'] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'q_color', true);
    $myOptions[$post_id]['q_bgcolor'] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'q_bgcolor', true);
    $myOptions[$post_id]['q_font'] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'q_font', true); 


    update_option('MyOptions', $myOptions);
}
    add_action( 'save_post', 'option_save_post', 10, 3 );

function metabox_inline_style($post_id) {

    $myOptions = get_option('MyOptions');

    foreach ( $myOptions as $myOption ) {

    $custom_metabox_css = "
        .quote-style {
            color: {$myOption['q_color']};
            background-color: {$myOption['q_bgcolor']};
            font-size: {$myOption['q_font']};
        }
        .quote-style p {
            color: {$myOption['q_color']};
        }"; 
    }
    wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_metabox_css );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'metabox_inline_style');
```